# ASP .NET Core Routing To Controllers in External Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url-routing

This is an article on ASP.NET Core routing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

It is straight forward. I can either specify a route like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Or I can mark my controllers and actions with attributes like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<string> Get(string id)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

But, I tried putting a controller in an external library with attributes, and referenced that assembly from my main service, and when I punch the Url in, the call is not routed to the controller. I'm guessing I need to tell ASP.NET Core which assemblies to scan through, but I don't know how. I am using this url BTW: http://localhost:5000/api/test/a.

Comment: Haha, here we meet again, I'm just in middle of writing the same question!
I need it to inject dummy controllers for testing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to tell ASP.NET Core in which assemblies it should look for controllers, you could use the concept called 'Application Parts'. There is an article on that right next to the URL that you posted in your question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Using that approach, you can even use controllers from the assemblies that are not referenced by your root application assembly, by loading the assemblies dynamically, based on settings in the application config file. Please refer to the example below:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // ...

  // load application parts from a non-referenced 'extension' assembly:
  var path = @"c:\extensions\CustomController.dll";
  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);

  services.AddMvc()
  .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
  .AddApplicationPart(assembly);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: This answer is basically correct. The only thing I was missing was to call AddApplicationPart with my external assembly. Could you please update with a straight forward code example?

Answer (score 0):

If you just reference external assembly but none of its types are explicitly used, the assembly will not be actually loaded and asp.net core will not have a chance to discover controllers within it.

To force loading of external assembly and fix your problem you could update startup routine with something simple like

```
var t = typeof(ExternalController);
```

where `ExternalController` is a controller from your external library.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this but it didn't solve my issue. Which part of the startup routine do I need to do this in order to make sure that the app domain has my assembly by the time it processes the routing.

Comment: Strange, I've tried this and it works fine. Try to add it to Startup.Configure() where routes are configured.

Comment: I'm wondering if my ASP.NET Core MVC NuGet packages have anything to do with this... I am on the latest version that is supported by .NET Framework.

Comment: Could you publish minimal example that reproduces your problem, on GitHub or somewhere else? Without it it's hard to say why controllers from external library aren't discovered in your case.

Comment: This is true, but it's not the end of the story. Even if the type is loaded, you still have to call AddApplicationPart or the controller will not be added.

Comment: That doesn't work. Even after forcing type the assembly load, the ASP.NET Core runtime doesn't discover its controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issues but using Umbraco. I've found a slightly different solution.

Umbraco supports finding and loading classes in external assemblies using the IComposer interface. Inside that class you can have access to a method called Compose. Maybe this concept can help you out too; fire off a request to look through the assemblies in the project folder. I'm using it to register DbContexts, controllers and interfaces. This way I don't have to updated, load/fanny about/meddle with the program or Umbraco itself; each assembly is self contained. You don't have it, or need it, for a specific project, that's fine, everything just carries on...

```
public class UmbracoDependencyInjection : IComposer
{
    public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped();
        builder.Services
            .AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

In this example I needed to add AddControllersWithViews because AppApplicationPart is an extension on IMvcBuilder.